# How to convert values of tuple from a dictionary into a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the values from a dictionary into a list.

`D = {"A": [(1, 2)], "B": [(3, 4), (5, 6)]}`

How do I get the following result?

`[[1, 2], [3,4], [5, 6]]`

I am trying to use max 1 for-loop

```
# My attempt
my_list = list(D.values())
print(my_list)
# [[(1, 2)], [(3, 4), (5, 6)]]
```

Comment: look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am able to do it if I use 2 for-loops but I am trying to only use 1. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: `list(map(list, sum(list(D.values()), [])))`

Answer (score 1):

As simple as a nested list comprehension:

```py
D = {"A": [(1, 2)], "B": [(3, 4), (5, 6)]}

my_list = [list(item) for val in D.values() for item in val]
```

Output:

```py
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension (bellow) or a for loop.

```
my_list = [v for k, v in D.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is still the same as my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using the way below you can do it:

```
my_dict = {'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (4, 5, 6), 'c': (7, 8, 9)}

# Convert tuple values to lists
my_list = [list(value) for value in my_dict.values()]

# Print the resulting list
print(my_list)
```

if it works, upvote it

Comment: The input is very different from what the question showed, and it will not work on the provided example.